# Scaling (zooming) CameraNode lags overtime

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, skcameranode

Im using Swift 3.0 and I'm attempting to use the SKCameraNode class as a camera for my game.

I move it around, rotate, and zoom in and out a lot. For some reason, it goes in and out of having these rough patches (about 30 seconds) where it's super etchy, as if it were only being updated a tenth of the usual time. Note that NOTHING else in the game is lagging except camera movement.

However this is only extremely noticeable when I'm trying to zoom in and out.

The occurrence usually happens after a burst of moving it around a lot, but not always. Sometimes it happens the second the app is started, and other times never.

Here is my code, which is running in **didFinishUpdate**:

```
camera.run(SkAction.scale(to: size, duration time))
```

time is usually 0.0, but sometimes not, so I would like to try to keep this as an SKAction if possible. However, I assume the problem resides in using this SKAction. (I'm like 99% sure the problem isn't that I'm accidentally not passing 0.0 for time)

So what should I do to either fix or work my way around this problem? Is this just a limitation of a Swift?

EDIT: I have now also tried using it in other update functions. I also tested to see the run time of didFinishUpdate (To see if it was lag), but it remained consistent. Also, this happens when i try to rotate the camera as well.
ANOTHER EDIT: I've also tried setting gamePhysics speed to 0.9999 which was suggested in another post with a lag problem

Thanks!